# Graphics stuttering in 3D Games

Tags: graphics-card, performance, gpu, nvidia-graphics-card

Every time I play a game, I experience random stuttering of video and the FPS counter very briefly goes down to 0.
This stuttering can be seen in this [YouTube video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=wmtZ07qHFS4&list=UUoAASU98g2jffZ_eHIdinug), with the most obvious stuttering occurring at 0:04.

I have verified that PhysX on my Nvidia GTX280 is switched to the card, not the CPU, and I've also verified that the card is running at 'Maximum performance' and not 'Adaptive'.

This occurs regardless of the graphics settings in the games, and I suffer no other issues related to the graphics or FPS.

I realise that the GTX280 is (by today's standards) 'ancient', but it still runs every game I throw at it on maximum graphics settings, but only with this small stuttering.
I wouldn't have an issue with it, but however the stuttering occurs most when a shot gets fired near me, or an explosion happens. Now, this would normally be related to the CPU, but my last graphics card that I had (an AMD Radeon HD7700 [the GTX280 is much better, besides the AMD card being newer]) never had this stuttering with the same system setup.

There's a [Wikipedia page](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Micro_stuttering) about this 'micro-stuttering', but I'm not operating on an SLi configuration.
[Apparently this issue](http://forums.steampowered.com/forums/archive/index.php/t-1586795.html) could be caused by PhysX using the CPU instead of the GPU, but I've verified that PhysX is using the GPU and not the CPU.
[This isn't an AMD GPU.](http://www.anandtech.com/show/6857/amd-stuttering-issues-driver-roadmap-fraps/5)
[I don't have Watchdogs, so I can't test this.](http://www.reddit.com/r/watch_dogs/comments/26h32u/watch_dogs_stuttering_fixed_buttersmooth/)

Is there a fix for this, and if so, how can this be fixed (please don't say 'upgrade your GPU', because that's not going to happen for a while)?

Comment: Post your `dxdiag` log

Comment: Try a fresh Windows install with the latest drivers.

Comment: @Ƭᴇcʜιᴇ007 Not exactly a good solution. I think I fixed it by switching off DEP, just testing it now.

Comment: It's not a good solution because you don't want to be bothered to do it? If you want to keep your existing OS, use a different HDD for testing, and/or make a system image backup before doing it.  The amount of time it sounds like you've spent trying random things off the Internet probably could have been used to reinstall and test, and then you'd know if you are dealing with a software or hardware issue, which helps IMMENSLY when diagnosing weird problems like this. If you don't want to spend the $$$ then you need to spend the time. ;)

Comment: @Ƭᴇcʜιᴇ007 No, it's not a good solution because it involves reinstalling the OS just to fix this small bug. I've spent literally 5 minutes trying stuff from the internet because there's not that much on the issue.

Comment: Sure thing, it's up to you as to how much work you want to do.  Good luck!

Comment: Feel free to continue to ignore the guy who could help but requires additional information.

Comment: @Ramhound He never required 'additional information'

Comment: @zyboxenterprises - **I was talking about myself**  I also was being sarcastic since I don't like being ignored.